# Counting argument for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^{j}\binom{n}{j}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

> Is there a counting argument for the following identity?
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^{j}\binom{n}{j}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{n}$$
>   where $n$ is a positive integer

**NOTE:** I do NOT need algebraic proofs. *I have already proved the identity*. I only want to know if there is a counting argument for the identity.

I stumbled across this identity while trying to prove 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+1)...(k+n)}=\frac{1}{n\cdot n!}$$
I am aware of the counting argument for $\sum_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^{j}\binom{n}{j}=0$, which involves producing a bijection from the set of all even subsets of $\{1,2,3,...n\}$ to the set of all odd subsets. However, I am not sure how one would put the $\frac{1}{k}$ together with the $(-1)^{j}\binom{n}{j}$.

Comment: Your identity has minus signs and fractions, so what exactly do you mean by "counting"? A reasonable first step for any proof is to simplify the inner sum $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(-1\right)^j \dbinom{n}{j}$ to $\left(-1\right)^{k-1} \dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$; this can be proven by sign-reversing involution (see the Third Solution to Exercise 4 on [UMN Fall 2018 Math 5705 homework set #2](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/18f/hw2s.pdf)). It then remains to prove $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(-1\right)^{k-1} \dbinom{n-1}{k-1} \dfrac{1}{k} = \dfrac{1}{n}$. This follows ...

Comment: ... easily from $\dbinom{n-1}{k-1} \dfrac{1}{k} = \dfrac{1}{n} \dbinom{n}{k}$ and the usual "alternating sum of binomial coefficients is $0$" identity. All of this can be made into a proof by sign-reversing involution provided that you multiply through by the denominators; it is like composing bijections, except you are composing sign-reversing involutions. But clothing the proof in such a cloak only obscures it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as
a telescoping series.

Let
$p_n(x)
=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+k)
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{p_n(x)}-\dfrac1{p_n(x+1)}
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+k)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+1+k)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+k)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{k=1}^{n} (x+k)}\\
&=\dfrac{(x+n)-x}{\prod_{k=0}^{n} (x+k)}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{p_{n+1}(x)}\\
\end{array}
$

so that

$\dfrac{1}{p_{n+1}(x)}
=\dfrac1{n}(\dfrac1{p_n(x)}-\dfrac1{p_n(x+1)})
$

and the series telescopes.

Also note that

$\begin{array}\\
p_n(x+1)-p_n(x)
&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+1+k)-\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+k)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n} (x+k)-\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+k)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (x+k)(x+n-x)\\
&=n\prod_{k=0}^{n-2} (x+1+k)\\
&=np_{n-1}(x+1)\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$\sum_k p_n(x+k)
$
also telescopes.